# Running aspx.cs in Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, service

I'm new to the whole concept of Windows service. I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. I have to execute a function periodically which is written in asp.net
2. I want to use a Windows service to schedule to that.

Can windows service do that? I don't want to open the web application for it to happen and it must run in the background at all times. This will be installed on the web server.

Sorry, if I couldn't frame my question better.

Please suggest me what should be done. Is there any other way or should I go ahead.

Comment: 'function written in asp.net', you mean webservice?

Answer (score 0):

There's not such thing like "function .. written in asp.net". You have to isolate the code of the function you want to run in a separate dll, and then call this code from your windows service.  If you install the dll in the GAC, you can share the code between your web app and the windows service.

Another solution is to expose the function as a web service (WCF or WebApi) and call it from your windows service too.

Asp.Net is not suitable for long running or periodically execution of code, that's why you need to separate both functionalities.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.